# Checking if user is active mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone I have a problem...this is my code; the function is to check whether a user has activated his/her account:

```
function is_active($username)
{
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    require "dbc.php";
    $sql="SELECT COUNT users_temp,user_id 
            FROM users1 AS s1
            INNER JOIN users_temp AS s2
            ON users1,id = users_temp,user_id
            WHERE users1,username='{$username}'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    return(mysql_result($result,0) == '0')? true : false;
}
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username='yu'' at line 5`

I don't see where I went wrong. It probably is a small mistake but if anyone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should use dot (.) to separate table and column name, not comma

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(users_temp.user_id) 
        FROM users1 AS s1
        INNER JOIN users_temp AS s2
        ON users1.id = users_temp.user_id
        WHERE users1.username='{$username}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT (users_temp.user_id) 
        FROM users1 AS s1
        INNER JOIN users_temp AS s2
        ON s1.id = s2.user_id
        WHERE users1.username = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use single quotes to quote fields in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here :

`WHERE users1,username='{$username}'`.

Do this instead  :

```
WHERE users1.username='$username'
```

Or this :

```
WHERE users1.username='".$username."'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have user1,username. That is wrong.

```
   $sql="SELECT COUNT users_temp,user_id 
    FROM users1 AS s1
    INNER JOIN users_temp AS s2
    ON users1,id = users_temp,user_id
    WHERE s1.username='$username'";
```

I hope this will help you .